# How to send a form in a foreach loop using PHP

Tags: php, html, css, opencart

I want to send an Id by the form in foreach loop but when I click on each button it sends me the first form.

It means when I click on the second button it sends me the value of the first form the value of input hidden is right but the first value every time sent.

```php
<?PHP 
if ($transactions) { 
    foreach ($transactions as $transaction) {
?>
    <td class="text-left">
        <?php echo $transaction['invoice_id']; ?>
    </td>
    <td class="text-left">
        <?php echo $transaction['invoice_type']; ?>
    </td>
    <td class="text-left">
        <?php echo $transaction['ref_id']; ?>
    </td>
    <td class="text-left">
        <?php echo $transaction['gateway']; ?>
    </td>
    <td class="text-left">
        <?php echo $transaction['payment_date']; ?>
    </td>
    <td class="text-right">
        <?php
            if($transaction['payment_status'] == 'not paid') { 
        ?>
            <form 
                method="POST" 
                action="<?php echo $gate_url; ?>"
            >
                <input type="hidden" name="invoiceId" value="<?php echo $transaction['invoice_id']; ?>">
                <button class="btn btn-md btn-primary" type="submit" >
                    <?php echo $pay; ?>
                </button>
            </form>
        <?php 
            }
        ?>
    </td>
<?php
}
```

Comment: Could you try to change the `type="hidden"` to `type="text"` to confirm what are the values you see? The code seems good to me. You may also try to debug the part that receiving the value for bugs, not only the form. Also, could you confirm that this code `<td class="text-left">
        <?php echo $transaction['invoice_id']; ?>
    </td>` returns back a different invoice id on each loop?

Comment: @KodeFor.Me: thanks for repairing the question here. However, I wonder if the code was so substantially reformatted, that it might mask a problem that existed already. In general, it may be worth leaving code as-is, unless it is so badly formatted that it is unreadable.

Comment: @halfer hello and thank you for your comments. Obviously the code was unreadable and that was the purpose of re-formatting it. At least from my side of view, it's impossible to help somebody when the code is not in a good state for reading, and I cannot also read code of few lines in just 2 - 3 lines with horizontal scrolling :)

Comment: have you tried the name value put into array `name="invoiceId[]"` ?

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of the values, so this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="invoiceId" value="<?php echo $transaction['invoice_id']; ?>">
```

replace with:

```
<input type="hidden" name="invoiceId[]" value="<?php echo $transaction['invoice_id']; ?>">
```